# Databinding not working - a function triggered when a date is picked changes a property but the DOM doesn't change

Tags: angular, data-binding, ionic2

In an Ionic2 project I have a `registers` array bound to a template, and a date-picker which triggers that `registers` array to be updated. The problem is that the update is not reflected in the DOM.

Here is the template:

```
{{ registers | json }}
<ion-datetime displayFormat="HH:mm:s" (ionChange)="makeAChange($event)"></ion-datetime>
```

Here is the makeAChange function:

```
makeAChange($event){
    this.registers.push({'in': new Date().toISOString(), 'out': new Date().toISOString()})
    console.log(this.registers)
  }
```

Registers is initialised as below:

```
ngAfterViewInit(){
    this.registers = [{
      'in': new Date().toISOString(),
      'out': new Date().toISOString()
    }]
  }
```

After picking a date, I log out the updated this.registers and it does have a second object added. But the registers json on the page doesn't change.

With a regular ion-button attached to makeAChange(), the change is made to the DOM successfully.

So is it not possible to use an input component like ion-datetime to change objects bound to the DOM? Or is there a way to get ion-datetime working in a way that triggers an update (of `registers` on the page) when a date is picked?

Any help and advice would be very appreciated.

(Note that this is the distillation of a problem I'm having getting updates to take effect as soon as a date is picked.)

**UPDATE**

The binding is working if the makeAChange() function gets called from a regular input element, when enter is pressed: `(keyup.enter)="makeAChange()"` works. The new object is added to the registers array and that is reflected in the DOM.

So why doesn't it work when the function is triggered from a date picker?

**UPDATE**

When the `<ion-datetime>` is in an `<ion-item>` element, the binding works. If anyone can explain what's going on that would be great!

Comment: hi have you made registers as public? something like: public registers : any[] ?

Comment: I declare `registers` as any at the top of the component.

Comment: try to put it as public

Comment: does it work?.. ?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting `this.registers.push(...)` in a zone like this:

```
import { NgZone } from '@angular/core';

export class MyPage {
  zone: NgZone;

  constructor() {
    this.zone = new NgZone({enableLongStackTrace: false});
  }

  makeAChange($event){
    this.zone.run(() => {
      this.registers.push({'in': new Date().toISOString(), 'out': new Date().toISOString()});
      console.log(this.registers);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. No luck though.